# Is it possible to access static files within views.py?

Tags: python, django

I am able to access the static file in question via direct url (`localhost:8000/static/maps/foo.txt`), so I guess I have it all working well. But I can't do the following: I want to open that text file in views.py. It's because I'm working on a simple web browser adventure game and I wanted to store maps in static/maps and load those maps using `f=open('/static/maps/' + mapname + '.txt', 'r')`. I get the `IOError: no such file or directory`. I really don't understand it, because there *is* such directory when I search for it in address.

Can it be done somehow?

Comment: `/static/maps/` would be in a directory called `static` at the root of your machine's filesystem, not at the local URL /static, which is probably being served from somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, and that is my problem. How to point to the static directory instead of the machine's root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the place they are stored on disk, which is probably in `settings.STATIC_ROOT` or `settings.STATICFILES_DIRS`, not the place they are being served by the web app.

Note however that if you are modifying these files programmatically, they aren't (by definition) static files. You'd be better off using the `MEDIA_ROOT` location. Also note that Django has helpers to do this sort of thing - see the documentation on [Managing files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/files/).

Comment: But it feels like using static files dirs depends on the machine I'm using. I'm running development server for now so it's ok, but what if I'll try to upload my project to a web server? Or to a git repository? Will it require some extra attention? Thanks!

Comment: Which is why you use the value from the settings, not hard code it in your view.

Comment: I don't get it :( my brain just can't wrap around this one. So does `settings.STATICFILES_DIRS` return the global static files directory? Or maybe I should use static root and have everyone else involved in this project copy static files into their root? Please help this poor noob understand how this all works! Thanks

Comment: You can set the directories relative to your project root; there are plenty of questions here and blogs elsewhere on how to do that. But as I say in my answer, files that you modify are not static files: you should use the MEDIA_ROOT directory, again set relative to your project root.

Comment: I'm not modifying those files, I just want to read them and extract some data out of them in views. But thanks for your help, I think I'm alright now!