# Save output objects from django-filter to a CSV

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, django-filter

I am have have a simple model in Django and I am using django-filters in one of my pages to have the simple functionality of having a form to search throug the models & then output a list of models and attributes.

What I need help with is how to get the set (of models data) that is selected in the django-filters form to be saved as CSV when I click 'Submit' on the form. I would also like to add a form box for how the file can be named.

models.py

```
    class Person(..)
         name = models.CharField(..)
         type = models.CharField(choices=TYPECHOICES)
         ...
```

filters.py

```
    class PersonFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        type = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(name='type', choices=TYPECHOICES)
```

views.py:

```
    def query(request):
        f = PersonFilter=request.GET, queryset=Person.objects.all())
        return render_to_response('query.html', {'filter': f})
```

finally in my template I have:

```
    {{ filter.form.as_p}}
```

and

```
    {% for obj in filter %}
    {% endfor %}
```

to put up the form & results.

Thanks

Edit:

When I do this in views, why do I iterate over ALL my objects instead of just the set specified by the form:

```
    for obj in f:
        print obj.name
```

This is really strange. Since in the template when I iterate over filter I only see the filtered set as per the form.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to achive. Do you want to display the objects as csv on the webpage or do you want to create a csv-file somewhere on the client's machine or somewhere on the server machine?

Comment: I am sure that there are better ways of getting at what I want to acheive.... BUT:

what I want is:
1. A web page where I can have a form to query my models, select a subset, output the subset as a list, and 'save' this queryset.
2. A separate page view in which I can select one of the previously saved query sets and make graphs of the data.

Comment: ... I wanted to use the view that I am working on now to dump the filtered data into a CSV on the server. Then on the graphs view I can select the dataset that I made and make graphs from the CSV

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [Is it possible to access static files within views.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208536/is-it-possible-to-access-static-files-within-views-py) on how to access static files in a view. And then it would be best IMHO if the Person object would have a method like `to_csv` or something.
So you could just call it for every object and simply write it to the csv file.

But I'm not sure if this is really the way you want to go.

You should think about creating the graph directly from the list of objects returned by the query, since you already have your query saved.

Comment: Thanks. Good idea. Would this still be possible if I want the graphs and the query form +list on separate web pages?

Comment: I guess I am confused about how my query is saved & how to access this.